# phpmyadmin held back, why and how to fix it?

Tags: apt, phpmyadmin

Today I am doing maintenance of the server Debian 8.4, and I don't know why phpmyadmin package has been held back, well I haven't solved such situation yet, so any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

`apt-get upgrade`

```
root@vb-srv-debian:/# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  phpmyadmin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

first off, my idea was to run `apt-get dist-upgrade`

```
root@vb-srv-debian:/# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Strange, right?

Ok, now what is in the policy:

```
root@vb-srv-debian:/# apt-cache policy phpmyadmin
phpmyadmin:
  Installed: 4:4.6.0-1.trusty~ppa.1
  Candidate: 4:4.6.1-1.trusty~ppa.1
  Version table:
     4:4.6.1-1.trusty~ppa.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4:4.6.0-1.trusty~ppa.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:4.2.12-2+deb8u1 0
        500 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Bad thing is, that here my knowledge ends, to be exact, I don't understand the policy, can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pulling in `phpmyadmin` from a Trusty PPA. The package there seems to be a straightfoward rebuild of the [`phpmyadmin` package in Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/phpmyadmin), but the latter [recently changed](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/phpmyadmin.git/commit/?id=80a81e7915ee35cd27f8521a314812f3f38bc9ff) to simplify its dependencies, using the new [`php-defaults` packages](https://tracker.debian.org/php-defaults). The resulting package can no longer be installed in Debian 8.

There is no easy solution to upgrade to version 4.6.1 of the Debian/Ubuntu packages. Typically I would recommend using the Jessie version (which gets security support), but downgrading phpMyAdmin might not be easy either (or possible at all)... You could always ask for a [backport](http://backports.debian.org/).

Comment: would `apt-get purge phpmyadmin`, removing the PPA, and then `apt-get install phpmyadmin` work in my case?

Comment: @burian.vlastimil if you don't mind losing the phpMyAdmin configuration, yes, with `apt-get update` after removing the PPA. You'll lose any new features introduced between phpMyAdmin 4.2 and 4.6 though!